# Sharepoint リストにある複数値カラムを別リストの値で更新

Tags: sharepoint

Sharepoint のリストに以下のカラムが定義されています。

リストA
・AID
・BIDList(複数値)

リストB(同一 AID を複数もつ)
・BID
・AID

複数該当する BID をリストAの複数列に更新したいのですが、Access での更新は単一値のみサポートで
複数値の更新ができないようです。
他に Flow が有効かと考えつきましたが、現在いろいろ試していますが、
いまだ解決に至っていません。

誰かご存知でしたら教えてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己レスです。Access VBA で組みました。複数列フィールドの値はレコードセットとして使えるので、AddNew->Updateしました。また、今回は参照列を更新するので、参照元のIDの値をそのまま入れて解決しました。